# When running "go test", is there a way to get a count of how many tests were run?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'd like to get the number of tests that were run with `go test`, as kind of a checksum to detect if all the tests are running. Since Go relies on filenames and method names to determine what's a test, it's easy to mistype something, which would mean the test would silently be skipped.

Comment: No, you would have to do this yourself, unless you want something like `go test list .`.  How would you use something like this, since in order to determine the "correct" number you also have to look at the filenames and function signatures.

Comment: All test frameworks I've used in the past give you a count of total/passed/failed tests. It's just useful to get an idea of if your tests are working as expected. For example, if you start developing a feature and there are 10 tests, and you add 2 more, you can expect to have 12 when you're done, and if you don't, then you know something is wrong.

Comment: I'm considering `go test -list`, but I would have to run it as a separate command. Ideally, it would be more convenient to get the number when I run `go test`, since it already knows it internally.

Comment: IMHO someone is just as likely to miss calculating the difference between the before and after test count as they are to miss an incorrect function name in the diff. I don't see any benefit to this, since tests should be automated and code review should be the norm, but regardless, there is no count output for `go test`.

Comment: You may not see a benefit, but I do. It's better than nothing, which is what Go currently provides.

Comment: There's a reason that every test framework in existence reports the number of tests. Go is the exception here.

Comment: Just run `go test && echo 38` if you just need some number. This number is not actionable and thus juts noise. Even in other test frameworks.

Comment: This is something I've long wished for, but alas, it's not provided by the Go testing library.

Comment: @JimB: There is value in having a test plan, which alerts you when an unexpected number of tests are executed. This can be an indication of accidentally disabling tests, or of non-deterministic tests.

Comment: "This number is not actionable and thus juts noise" -- The number _is_ actionable, and is _not_ noise. Other test frameworks I've used can cause a test suite to fail if an unexpected number of tests run.

Comment: @Flimzy: that's fine if you create the framework to handle the number of tests changing. This is outside the purview of `go test`, but that isn't to say something couldn't be added to your own workflow. I have failures when coverage drops below a certain threshold -- you can wire up whatever you want under `make test`, but I'm not insisting `go test` add coverage tracking too.

Comment: @JimB: I'm not arguing that it's aprt of `go test`--I'm arguing that the use case is valid, and that `go test` would be the natural place to solve it, so the request from the OP is not unreasonable.

Comment: @frodo2975 I think you want https://github.com/gotestyourself/gotestsum. And I see from where you are coming from. TAP has the same behavior: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol

Comment: @Flimzy: I'm also not saying it couldn't be useful, but it's only noise if it's not actionable, and it's not actionable if you don't have a baseline to compare to. Most test systems would get the number from the merge base, which the Go tool has no knowledge of.

Comment: @marco.m gotestsum looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Would you mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: @frodo2975 done

Comment: `go test | grep -c "RUN"`, will give you the count.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the [gotestsum](https://github.com/gotestyourself/gotestsum) tool is close to what you are looking for.
It is a wrapper around `go test` that prints formatted test output and a summary of the test run.

Default `go test`:

```
go test ./...
?       github.com/marco-m/timeit/cmd/sleepit   [no test files]
ok      github.com/marco-m/timeit/cmd/timeit    0.601s
```

Default `gotestsum`:

```
gotestsum 
∅  cmd/sleepit
✓  cmd/timeit (cached)

DONE 11 tests in 0.273s            <== see here
```

Checkout the documentation and the built-in help, it is well-written.

In my experience, gotestsum (and the other tools by the same organization) is good. For me, it is also very important to be able to use the standard Go test package, without other "test frameworks". gotestsum allows me to do so.

On the other hand, to *really* satisfy your requirement (print the number of declared tests and verify that that number is actually ran), you would need something like TAP, the [Test Anything Protocol](http://testanything.org/), which works for any programming language:

```
1..4                               <== see here
ok 1 - Input file opened
not ok 2 - First line of the input valid
ok 3 - Read the rest of the file
not ok 4 - Summarized correctly # TODO Not written yet
```

TAP actually is very nice and simple. I remember there was a Go port, [tap-go](https://github.com/mndrix/tap-go), but it is now marked as archived.