# Is the go test coverage.out file able to show how many tests were run?

Tags: go, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, go-testing

I have a project in go lang, I can run tests and sonar can identify the total percentage of test coverage. But I want to know if I can generate any metrics in this `coverage.out` file that can show how many tests were run so that sonar can display this information.

I'm running the command `go test -cover -coverprofile=coverage.out ./...` and it's generating the file for me with just the percentage of each test, but I need to know how to generate a metric of how many tests were run in total so that sonar is able to show this information.

Comment: `go test -cover` does not provide number of tests that are run. [gotestsum](https://github.com/gotestyourself/gotestsum) is a tool that provide this information as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230962/when-running-go-test-is-there-a-way-to-get-a-count-of-how-many-tests-were-run

Comment: @kaushik the gotestsum it shows the amount of tests run for me in terminal or file generated, but not for sonar, that's my problem.

Comment: @MuriloAlves I'm about to hook up sonar to my golang project as well. Curious, what does the sonar report look like with just the native report? How is it lacking from other languages with better support? Can sonar use gotestsum?